# Less CSS problems referencing namespaced function

Tags: less

I've started using namespaces in Less CSS and come across an irregularity that seems to be a bug rather than by design.

```
#responsive {
    .spacing {
        .margin(@property; @side) {
            // This WON'T work when called externally.
            .margin(@property; @side; @side; @side; @side);
        }
        .margin(@property; @vertical; @horizontal) {
            // This WILL work when called externally.
            #responsive.spacing.margin(@property; @vertical; @horizontal; @vertical; @horizontal);
        }
        .margin(@property; @top; @right; @bottom; @left) {
        // This is the function that eventually gets called
        }
    }
}
```

The example shows an overloaded function with 3 different signatures. It's called as follows:

```
#responsive.spacing.margin(padding, 1);
```

When referencing the top overload, which then calls the main function, I get a compilation error.

```
.margin cannot be referenced...
```

This can be fixed by applying the fully namespaced name as in the second option.

While this is a workaround, it seems to counter what namespacing is about, after all `.margin` is simply calling another version of `.margin` inside the same namespace, `#responsive.spacing`.

Comment: Yes, that would be a bug - but I can't reproduce it with one of current Less version (though right now I'm away of my main computers so I can try only online compilers - e.g. [1](https://less.pytes.net/), [2](https://less.pytes.net/), both represent some v3.x I guess). So more info on what version (and/or what tool exactly) you're using is needed.

Comment: @seven-phases-max - this is where it gets confusing. I'm using Web Essentials for Visual Studio 2017, BuildWebCompiler v1.12.394. So, don't know what exact version I'm using.

Comment: @seven-phases-max - one thing I should add - I tend to be very granular, so the referenced element and the calling element will be in different Less files.

Comment: Ah, sorry I've actually missed your actual "error" among other words. When you call the mixin like `#responsive.spacing.margin` the other mixins within it should use fully qualified name (i.e. like in your workaround). Basically it's illogical language defect (it is as old as [#57](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/57), though the more up-to-date issue is #996), but because it emerges from another much more complex and complicated stuff (like #2212 and #1316) there were not attempts to improve that as far as I know

Comment: @seven-phases-max - thanks for your input. I'm guessing that, since #57 originates from 2010, there's no fix on the horizon. I'll continue with my workaround.